How make this table? And which package more helpful for these tables
I need help creating this table, I don't know which package to use and how to start it…

Thnx in advance!

Welcome to TeX.SE! Has this table a special name?

Welcome. // Did you try to search the many table-related Q&A on this site? (Search help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

The following is a very basic version in TikZ drawing your image. It's using grid for the rules and places nodes at each intersection (using anchor=... to shift those nodes such that they don't touch the lines). Most likely there is a fancier variant using TikZ to get this working, but this should be rather easy to alter if the need arises. To change the size of your grid simply specify x=<size>, xstep=<size> to change the horizontal size, and y=<size>, ystep=<size> to change the vertical one.
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[x=1.5cm,xstep=1.5cm]
    (0,0) grid (3, 3)
    (0,0) node[anchor=east]{1000}
    (0,1) node[anchor=east]{2000}
    (0,2) node[anchor=east]{2000}
    (0,3) node[anchor=east]{3000}
    (1,0) node[anchor=north]{500}
    (2,0) node[anchor=north]{0}
    (3,0) node[anchor=north]{0}
    (1,3) node[anchor=south]{1000}
    (2,3) node[anchor=south]{1000}
    (3,1) node[anchor=west]{0}
    (3,2) node[anchor=west]{500}
    (3,3) node[anchor=west]{1000}
    (1,1) node[anchor=south west]{$u_3$}
    (2,1) node[anchor=south west]{$u_4$}
    (1,2) node[anchor=south west]{$u_1$}
    (2,2) node[anchor=south west]{$u_2$}
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Maybe with Tikz!
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale = 0.8]%xscale = 1
        \draw (0,0) grid (3,3); %grid
        
        %numbers at left
        \foreach \n/\N in {0/1000,1/2000,2/2000,3/3000}{ %y component / label
            \node[anchor = east] at (0,\n) {\N};
        }
        
        %numbers at right
        \foreach \n/\N in {1/0,2/500,3/1000}{ %y component / label
            \node[anchor = west] at (3,\n) {\N};
        }
        
        %numbers at top
        \foreach \n/\N in {1/1000,2/1000}{ %x component / label
            \node[anchor = south] at (\n,3) {\N};
        }
        
        %numbers at bottom
        \foreach \n/\N in {1/500,2/0,3/0}{ %x component / label
            \node[anchor = north] at (\n,0) {\N};
        }
        
        \tikzset{u/.style = {anchor = south west, font = \small}} %style for inner labels
        
        \node[u] at (1,1) {$u_3$}; %coordinate of south west corner.
        \node[u] at (1,2) {$u_1$};
        \node[u] at (2,1) {$u_4$};
        \node[u] at (2,2) {$u_2$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


